# Maximum vertical distance between the line $y = x + 30$ and the parabola $y = x^2$ for $−5 ≤ x ≤ 6$

Tags: calculus, optimization, problem-solving

> What is the maximum vertical distance between the line $y = x + 30$ and the parabola 
>   $y = x^2$ for $−5 ≤ x ≤ 6$?

This is what I did but didn't work:

Set $y_1=x+30$ and $y_2=x^2$, plugged those into the distance formula [assuming $x=a$, $d=\sqrt{(y2-y1)^2}$ and get $d(x)=x^2-x-30$.

Assuming this is correct, I found the derivative of the equation to determine $x$ and then used the $x$ into $d(x)=x^2-x-30$ to find $y$ but my answer is wrong. Where is my mistake?

Comment: The distance=$|x^2-x-30|$. Find the value of $x$ which maximizes this using the method 'perfecting the square'. Consider the given range of $x$ too.

Comment: [Here's the notation used here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: You don't even need derivatives, your function $d(x)=x^2-x-30$ ($=-f(x)$ with $f$ defined in my answer) is a convex parabola. So you want to find its minimum. You may factorize $d$ and find its zeroes. Then you can find its vertex (exactly in the middle of its zeroes) which gives you the point $x^*$ at which $d(x^*)$ is minimum.

Comment: @Mathi doing that I get $(x-.5)^2-30.25$ but -30.25 was incorrect. That's the same answer as I would get following the method I posted above.

Comment: Answer must be $30.25$. that's why I put this as an absolute value

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Maximize the (quadratic!) function $f(x) = x+30-x^2$ on $[-5,6]$.